# Finding the scalar potential for a vector field that has an arbitrary function that determines its magnitude.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-fields, scalar-fields

This university problem is causing me problems, I have already proven the vector field is conservative but I can't get its corresponding scalar field. The problem is, **a** is a vector field where **a** = **r**f(r) where **r** is the position vector and f(r) is an arbitrary function of r = |r|. Find the scalar potential.

I have made an attempt and got an answer, but know its wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please show your attempt.